# Are my phone contacts notified when I install WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When I install WhatsApp, I read that it tries to add all other WhatsApp-registered numbers in my phone Contacts list to my WhatsApp contacts.

Are all of these contacts then notified about this, or is this strictly just convenience on my end, while remaining quiet to other users?

Answer (score 3):

> Are all of these contacts then notified about this, or is this strictly just convenience on my end, while remaining quiet to other users?

No, contacts are not notified. They are notified only if you message them. However, if they view their WhatsApp contacts, then they can view your name there.